# Can "fire together, wire together" be undone?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience

Are new connections continuously forged in the adult human brain, or do we just start all wired together and then prune until we have something we like?

Comment: I believe it is a bit of both. But that will likely depend per brain region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Development of patterns of synaptic connection contains elements of both outgrowth and pruning. For example, this paper from zebrafish development illustrates both those mechanisms, which appear to be tightly linked:

> Meyer MP, Smith SJ. 2006. Evidence From in Vivo Imaging That Synaptogenesis Guides the Growth and Branching of Axonal Arbors by Two Distinct Mechanisms. Journal of Neuroscience 26:3604–3614.

In more advanced animals (e.g. cats), there is also evidence for both outgrowth and pruning:

> Callaway EM, Katz LC. 1990. Emergence and Refinement of Clustered Horizontal Connections in Cat Striate Cortex. Journal of Neuroscience 10:1134–1153.

There is also evidence for generation of new neurons in adult humans, which implies that new synaptic connections must be forged to integrate newborn neurons into existing networks:

> Ericsson et al. 1998. Neurogenesis in the adult human hippocampus. Nature Medicine 4:1313-1317.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "fire together, wire together" comes from an explanation of [Hebbian Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory) and refers to the adaptation of synapses as a response to the firing of already connected neurons. This is one of several [Synaptic Plasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_plasticity) mechanisms. Two others that exist are [Long Term Potentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_potentiation) (strengthening and creation) and [Long Term Depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_depression) (weakening and destruction).

All of these mechanisms are still being researched heavily to understand their detail better. However, I hope this gives you a good starting point.